# ASP.net Core ResponseCache and RedirectToAction. How can anonymous only responses be cached?

Tags: caching, asp.net-core, redirecttoaction, responsecache

Given the following controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ResponseCache(VaryByQueryKeys = new string[] { "id" }]
    public async IActionResult Action1(string id)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
           return RedirectToAction("Action2", new {id = id});

        return View();
    }


    [Authorize]
    public async IActionResult Action2(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Suppose an authenticated user navigates to "/Mycontroller/Action1/20". Would the response be cached?

If the answer is yes, how can anonymous only responses be cached?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you're showing here, the answer is no. The RedirectToAction will issue a separate request (a 301 redirect) to your site, which will be handled completely independently from the first request (to Action1).

It is worth considering the effects of response caching on non-anonymous users, but in this case your scenario would be safe from these potential effects.